# Rails - Ajax call renders my action and the parent page

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

in the `new` action of my `contracts` controller, I have an ajax link to a non RESTful action

```
<%= link_to "Select negotiation", negotiations_list_negotiations_path(:user_id => current_user), {:remote => true, :id => 'related_negotiation_add_link',  'data-controls-modal'=>"related_negotiation", 'data-backdrop' => true, 'data-keyboard'=> true} %>
```

This link populates a list of records in a modal window (I'm using Twitter's bootstrap modal here).

It works pretty well, but I've discovered by looking at my logs that it also made a call to the `new` action again. see the logs below (I've removed the SQL parts):

```
Started GET "/negotiations/negotiations_list?user_id=65" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-03 15:47:24 +0100
  Processing by NegotiationsController#negotiations_list as JS
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"65"}
Rendered negotiations/negotiations_list.js.erb (18.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 78ms (Views: 24.7ms | ActiveRecord: 21.7ms)


Started GET "/contracts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-03 15:47:24 +0100
  Processing by ContractsController#new as */*
Rendered contracts/_submenu.html.erb (6.2ms)
Rendered shared/_category_dropdown.html.erb (14.0ms)
Rendered contracts/_form.html.erb (199.8ms)
Rendered contracts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (213.7ms)
Rendered shared/_flash.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 260ms (Views: 238.1ms | ActiveRecord: 18.3ms)
```

Can anyone please explain while the `/contracts/new` action is triggered again, and how to stop this?